# Cannot create instance of ViewModel with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

It looks like I have problems with using Hilt.
I get the following error.
Maybe I need to add something to AppModule or something. I'm not sure...
[image]

I use the following dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2"
annotationProcessor  "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
annotationProcessor  "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```

My ViewModel class looks like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CurrencyViewModel  @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: CurrencyConverterImpl,
    private val dispatchers:DispatcherProvider
): ViewModel(){
```

The activity is like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CurrencyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel: CurrencyViewModel by viewModels()
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent ::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyApi(): CurrencyApi = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Utils.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(CurrencyApi::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyConverter(api: CurrencyApi): CurrencyConverter = CurrencyConverterImpl(api)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDispatchers(): DispatcherProvider = object : DispatcherProvider {
        override val main: CoroutineDispatcher
            get() = Dispatchers.Main
        override val io: CoroutineDispatcher
            get() = Dispatchers.IO
        override val default: CoroutineDispatcher
            get() = Dispatchers.Default
        override val unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher
            get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined

    }
}
```

UPDATE:
It looks like Hilt didn't like that I put something to the constructor. It needed a constructor without parameters.
But the question is how do I pass the CurrencyConverter repository and DispatcherProvider to ViewModel?

[image]
[image]

If I pass any parameter I also get this exception:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your `CurrencyViewModel` constructor, try replacing:

```kotlin
private val repository: CurrencyConverterImpl
```

with:

```kotlin
private val repository: CurrencyConverter
```

Your `@Provides` function is providing the interface, so you need to inject the interface. Besides, that improves testability of the viewmodel, as you can supply a test double (e.g., mock or fake) in unit tests.

Comment: Please check the update on my question.

Comment: @Alex20280: "It needed a constructor without parameters" -- how have you concluded this?

Comment: I have updated the question once again. I also get InstantiationException if I have parameters in ViewModel. But it's quite strange. How can I pass parameters then...

Comment: @Alex20280: Is this your first Hilt viewmodel in this project? If so, perhaps there is some configuration that you are missing somewhere. It might help if you put the entire stack trace in your question, as text.